# Matlab functions and parallel_invoke

Tags: c++, matlab, parallel-processing, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

In my project I have a lot of MATLAB functions. For each function I call Initialize function, when the application starts. I tried to call this functions using parallel_invoke. I tried it several times and allways it takes more time, that code without this. Can somebody explain this ?
Is there is something specific in MATLAB or Initialize functions ?

Comment: your question is not clear.. Are you working with Intel TBB library in C++? how do you integrate with MATLAB?

Comment: Which parallel_invoke? MS? TBB? Some code might help.

Answer (score 1):

The Matlab Runtime only has a single interpreter thread, so calling Matlab functions in parallel does not gain you anything: when the first function A is called, the MCR acquires a lock and only releases it when that function exits. Calling another function B during that period results in trying to acquire the lock, which then obviously just blocks until A finishes. The reason you see it taking up more time is probably due to the overhead of the locking/parallel_invoke.

I'm not sure what you mean with *for each function I call Initialize function*: unless you are using multiple Matlab dlls (which will afaik be less performant than having a single dll) you only need to call it's Initalize/Terminate once.

Comment: +1 makes sense now what OP meant by "initialize functions". Here some context for others not familiar with MATLAB Compiler: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/02/03/creating-c-shared-libraries-and-dlls/, and a [comment](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/02/03/creating-c-shared-libraries-and-dlls/#comment-32017) from Peter Webb confirming this fact about the use of semaphores for locking.

Comment: I use C++ in Visual Studio 2010